# Machine Learning Model for Multi-Label Classification where we know relationship between the labels

Tags: machine-learning

I am having a problem at hand where,

I need to classify the input data to one or more of the labels S1, S2, S3, S4

There is a relationship between the labels S1, S2, S3 and S4 which is,

If input is labelled Sn it must be labelled S1..Sn.

S1, S2, S3 and S4 are like different stages for an entity X to pass through. Based on input data X might get through one or many of the stages, X must pass through S1 to go to S2, S2 to go to S3 and so on

**We want to ensure that only those X are allowed to pass which reach S3**, so based on input data we decide whether to allow X to go through S1 or not

What machine learning models can we choose to predict if X reaches S3 if we have information like, input data and what stages X has passed for that input data

I am thinking in direction of a multi label classification There might be some relationship between input data stage S1 and S2

Update: I have to train with examples like
1. Input data is s1
2. Input data is s2
3. ..
4 ..

Comment: This sounds more like ordinal regression than multilabel classification.

Comment: any suggestions on how ordinal regression can be used for this ??

Comment: Have the s_n be the dependent variable, and the features be the independent variables. The just learn a regression model, which will implicitly enforce the ordinal constraints (however, this interpretation may not make sense for your classes)

Answer (score 0):

## Some doubts

Your question is far from being clear, for example:

> We want to optimize that most X reaches S3, so based on input data we decide whether to allow X to go through S1 or not

Actually suggest, that the best model would be "always answer yes" ,as it maximized number of objects reaching S3 (as it simply lets any object reach this point)

## General ideas

I assume two possible interpretations:

1. You have a labels "pipeline", which simply means, that object cannot be labelled `S_n` if it has not been already labelled with all `S_i` for `i < n`

   This does not seem to be the problem for one single model, you can pipeline models in a natural way, ie. train a model `1` which regognizes, if object `x` should have label `S_1`. Next, you train a model `2` on all data that has label `S_1` in the training set and predict label `S_2`, and so on. During execution you simply ask each model `i` if it accepts (labels) the incoming object `x`, and stop when the first one says "no"
2. You have some more complex constraints on the labels, which may be strict or not.For such cases, you should try one of many methods of `multi label classification with constraints`, in particular there is a [tech report](http://www.ke.tu-darmstadt.de/publications/reports/tud-ke-2008-04.pdf) regarding this aspect of ML.

## Solution 1 - approximating test functions

If your problem can be described as:

- You have data points `X`, such that for each of them you know the maximum number of some pipelineable tests `T_i` which `x` passes
- You want to train a classifier able to predict, what is the maximum number of consequtive tests that your point `x` passes
- You do not have access to actual tests `T_i` or they are very inefficient

Then the simplest way would be to apply the following training procedure instead of one classifier:

1. Take all your data points, label those with `y=0` as `0` and those with `y>=1` as `1`  and train some **binary classifier** (for example SVM). So you simply temporarly relabel your data so it shows points that pass the first test and those who don't. Lets call this classifier `cl_1`
2. Now take your data points, label those with `y=1` as `0` and those with `y>=2` as `1` and again train binary classifier, and call it `cl_2`
3. Repest until all tests have their classifier, in general in we call the classifier `cl_i` when it can distinguish between points labeled with `y=i-1` and those with `y>=i`.

Now, to classify your new point, you simply check iteratively all your `cl_i` for `i=1,..,tests` and answer with the largest such `i` that `cl_i(x)=1`. So you "simulate" your tests with classifiers, and simply say how many this tests' approximations it passed.

To sum up: each test can be approximated with one binary classifier, and then the question of "What is the biggest consequtive test number that our point passes" is approximated with "what is the biggest consequtive classifier number that out point is classified as true".

## Solution 2 - simple regression

You can also simply apply regression from your input space into the number of tests it reaches. Regression actually has an imprinted assumption, that the output values are correlated. So if you train your data with pairs `(x,y)` where `y` is the number of last test passed by `x`, then you are actually using the fact, that the output `y=3` is highly related to first getting `y=2` in the computations. Such regression (non-linear!) could be simply done using neural networks (possibly regularized)